# Which type of access_token will be passed in posting feed on facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am little bit confused about sending access token when we are posting feed on facebook. i was reading [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#publishing) article for posting feed. This shows:

```
POST graph.facebook.com
/{user-id}/feed?
message={message}&
access_token={access-token}
```

Please give me some example to posting feed on user wall. i got a approval of `publish_actions` too from facebook. thanks.

Comment: You use a user access token to post on the users feed. And page access token to post on a page

Comment: So, all actions your app does on facebook are done on behalf of the user. So posting user's access token is required for all actions like posting feeds or creating an ad campaign. The token includes permissions granted.

Comment: @WizKid thanks for reply. Ok so would you please send me some code or link to get user access token.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Finally, now i know the problem is the permission issue. We will pass the `AppAccessToken` in my thread above. My user id didn't have the `publish_actions` permission. Thanks.